# How do I sync live account via outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007

I just added my `email@live.com` in Microsoft Office Outlook 2007, I selected auto configuration settings, I am able to send/receive emails but what I want is if I delete it from my PC, I want that mail to be deleted from the server (i.e live.com) account too.

How do I configure it?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the account under server settings (if IMAP) uncheck leave copy on server (IMAP I believe synchronizes changes). If you can find the IMAP protocol settings I'd reconfigure for that.

If POP3, I don't believe it allows for that type of synchronization.

Not 100% on this though as it's been awhile since I used outlook.

Comment: I don't want to take that copy in my system, windows live essentials, what live software does is it syncs continuously, so if I delete a mail from my pc, it gets deleted from server too

Comment: It depends on the protocol used. You can google for programs that sync for you, but to my knowledge its the protocol that you use to access the server